# nginx gives error "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config

Nginx no longer starts. This error started happening after running out of storage. This error was not happening before, and I have not change the config. **I know there are many other questions with the same error, but none of them helped.**

here is my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name <domain>;

    root /var/www/pterodactyl/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:<php_socket>;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Here is the output of `nginx -T`

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an nginx configuration file but a vhost configuration file that should be placed at the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` (or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` if you prefer that type of vhost configuration files organization; see the [Difference in sites-available vs sites-enabled vs conf.d directories](https://serverfault.com/questions/527630/difference-in-sites-available-vs-sites-enabled-vs-conf-d-directories-nginx) thread at ServerFault to find out the difference) directory. You can check the whole nginx configuration file [example](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/nginx.conf) at the nginx GitHub mirror.

Those vhost configuration files are usually being included from the main configuration file at the `http` configuration level:

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and the Debian-based packages (or any other packages using those `sites-enabled`/`sites-available` directories) have an additional line there:

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

To find an original `nginx.conf` file for your particular Ubuntu distro, download the appropriate `nginx-common` package and check its contents.

Comment: Why is this an issue after working correctly before?

Comment: I can't believe it could work as a single nginx configuration file before (or ever).